# I got this error in this function: Invalid operands 'float' and 'Vector2' in operator '!='

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
func move(motion):
    if motion != Vector2():
        target_angle = atan2(motion.x, motion.y) - PI/2
        Skin.set_rot(target_angle)
```

I tried converting vectors to ints. I looked up this error and didnt understand fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `motion != Vector2()` mean?

It is comparing two things to see if the are different:

- `motion` a variable parameter of the function `move` which is Variant (it does not have a declared type).
- `Vector2()` this is the default constructor of the `Vector2` type. It should be equivalent to `Vector2.ZERO` or `Vector2(0.0, 0.0)`.

Now, the error is telling you that you got a `float`, and that Godot does not know how to compare `float` and `Vector2`.

You might have expected that checking if a `float` is different from a `Vector2` would return `true` (a `float` is different from a `Vector2`), but no, the comparison is an error. *Yes, I tried.* Otherwise the execution flow would enter the conditional and try to execute `atan2(motion.x, motion.y)` with a `float` and that would be error.

**This means you need to ensure it is a `Vector2` before comparing it with another `Vector2`.**

You could have prevented getting a `float` here by declaring the type of the parameter:

```
func move(motion:Vector2):
    if motion != Vector2():
        target_angle = atan2(motion.x, motion.y) - PI/2
        Skin.set_rot(target_angle)
```

And now it would give you an error where you are calling it with a `float`. *Why or where are you calling it with a float? I don't know. Presumably if you are getting the error in runtime you can also find out by looking at the stack on the debugger panel when the error shows up. Otherwise, this is a sure way to find out.*

*By the way, aren't the parameters of `atan2` backwards? Are you aware of `motion.angle()`?*

Anyway, Bugfish is right that you can check if the type of `motion` is `Vector2` in runtime, for example: `typeof(motion) == TYPE_VECTOR2`.

If I understand correctly you claim you did this: `var motion = Vector2()`. Well, something else happened somewhere, and we cannot find it for you. I presume you change the value of `motion` somewhere (that is the point of having a variable) perhaps set it to the return value of a function `var motion = get_motion()` or similar, and it sometimes returns a `float`...

Which, reminds me, you can also specify what your methods return. This method returns nothing (`void`):

```
func move(motion:Vector2) -> void:
    if motion != Vector2():
        target_angle = atan2(motion.x, motion.y) - PI/2
        Skin.set_rot(target_angle)
```

And this one returns a `Vector2`:

```
func get_motion() -> Vector2:
    return Input.get_vector("ui_left", "ui_right", "ui_up", "ui_down")
```

Yes, GDScript has static types, use them!

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like your parameter motion does not contain a Vector2, but a float value. Where do you call the function and did you already check if the functions gets the parameter you wanted to pass it?

Also before using a vatiable with unknown type, You should check the type, before assuming it's an Vector.

One way would be to check it's type:

```
if typeof(motion) != TYPE_VECTOR2:
   return
```

Comment: The point in this function is that var motion = Vector2(), so this function checks if this is true

Comment: Did you debug it to make sure?